# Procesamiento de NodeJS a JSON

Tags: php, angularjs, json, nodejs

Estoy intentado de procesar de NodeJS a JSON, la idea es desarrollar un campo de texto "autocomplete" con AngulaJS, pero estoy con el problema que el controlador no me funciona correctamente para poder mostrar los datos en el HTML. Lo estuve probando con w3schools y funciona bien:

```
$http({url: "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php", 
           method: "GET",
           params: {value: $scope.usuario}
      }).success(function(usuarios) {
        $scope.usuarios = usuarios.records;

      });
```

Pero cuando coloco el path (localhost:3000) del archivo nodeJS o php (he probado de todo), no me compila a JSON, por lo tanto no puedo hacer funcione el "autocomplete".
Se que el script de php y node están bien, pero me resulta raro que en vez de entregarme un array, me muestra el código completo en texto plano.
Saludos y gracias de antemano!!!!

Comment: y el texto te recibes es lo que deberías recibir pero como texto? entonces seguramente te falta una cabecera en la petición de este tipo 'Content-Type: application/json'. A ver si van por ahí los tiros

Comment: tengo la cabecera en cada respuesta: (php) echo $json_response = json_encode($arr); (nodejs)header('Content-Type: application/json'), pero si me sigue haciendo lo mismo. He revisado el servidor y esta todo bien. Lo que intento hacer, hasta que pueda resolver este tema, es crear un JSON con nodejs e importarlo desde un servidor JSON con nodejs, pero estoy probando. Gracias por tu comentario Spidvmp

Comment: Por si sirve de algo,se que no es la solucion, pero termine ejecutando el json fuera del servidor de NodeJS, en Apache http://localhost/json/json.php y desde ahí pude llamar el json. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El resultado era tan simple como colocar

```
fs.writeFile('./views/jsondb/jsonfile.json', JSON.stringify(rows), function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('json creado!');

});
```

Y luego llamar a la ruta desde angular con $http.

Saludos